# KC file change monitor keeps restarting during WAS 9 startup in RAD 9

Tags: ibm-rad

I'm setting up IBM RAD 9 on a new Windows machine. When I start the server (WAS V9.0 Traditional) the console is flooded with errors related to the KC file change monitor and it keeps on restarting every second or so, so I'm not even able to jump to a different view, such as Server view. It keeps on going until I stop the server.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on and how to stop this from happening?

Thank you.

I checked the logs but don't have an explanation. The error is 000122a4 KCConfig      I com.ibm.kc.config.KCConfig$2$1 uncaughtException Restarting KC file change monitor.